# HTML AntiForgery Token not working with Angular 5 SPA

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, angular5, single-page-application

I have an Asp.Net MVC 5 with Angular 5 SPA.
In my index.cshtml page I've added

```
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

this creates hidden token value and a cookie.

Now, I read the hidden token value and attach it to the headers for post call using Angular interceptor.

In my Web API controller, I do get the token and cookie values correctly.
However, the statement,

```
      AntiForgery.Validate(tokenCookie, tokenHeader);
```

throws invalid token error.

NOTE: cookie value is same through out the session. But hidden token value changes when I navigate. Not sure about how this is happening in a SPA.

Let me know if any idea on this.